# Parallel processing of files

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a requirement where I need to process multiple files parallely,I have done the below,Its working fine but how can I make it more optimal,looking forward to any suggestions.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        File [] files=new File("C:\\ftp").listFiles();
        //System.out.println(files.length);
         ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
           // System.out.println("available processors.."+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        if(files.length>=1)
        {
            for(int i = 0;i<files.length; i++){
                System.out.println("reading..."+i);
                Runnable workerThread = new FileWorkerThread(files[i]);
               executor.execute(workerThread);
                          }
            executor.shutdown();
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            }
```

//then I have a run() which is basically reading /writing to the files.Is this a good approach,Is there anything which I can do to make it better.

Comment: Use `executor.awaitTermination(...)` after shutting down instead of a busy loop.

Comment: You have a busywait as your last call, this is **very** bad practice. Use `executor.awaitTermination(...)` as suggested by @Pyranja.

Comment: Thank you all,I would make the changes,I addition I have to insert into database the contents of the file after getting the desired values ,would that be any issue regarding database lock or in getting database connections as there will be threads competing with each other for accessing the database.
@NishantShreshth ,bettter in the sense that whether it can be made more optimal do that it take less time.

Comment: There isn't as much advantage to this as you might think, unless the processing is CPU-bound. If it is I/O bound there is no advantage to multiple threads: there is still only one disk.

Comment: Hi EJP,there will be lots of complex logic processing with the data fetched from the files so I guess this fits into the purpose of multithreading..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the busy wait issue, already explained in the comments, there are no obvious problems with the code. So given that it works fine, as you said, ask yourself: Is there any need to change it? What aspect(s) would you want to improve by changing the code?

Out of the blue some hints to give you ideas:

- Creating an ExecutorService is a rather heavy-weight operation. But you can create a single service once (e.g. on application start) and reuse it throughout the application's runtime.
- If you would like to move work out of or collect results from the async tasks, consider implementing the `Callable<T>` interface instead of `Runnable`/`Thread` and use `executor.submit(...)`. It will return a `Future<T>`, which holds the result as soon as the asynchronous task is completed.